# MySQL if else statement with multi query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new on MySQL
I wanna use IF else statement in query that is

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT user_token 
            FROM upvotes 
            WHERE user_token ="user_token" AND comment_token = "comment_token"
           )
   ) 
THEN (DELETE 
      FROM upvotes 
      WHERE user_token = 'user_token' AND comment_token = "comment_token"
     ) 
     AND 
     (UPDATE comments 
      SET upvote = upvote +1 
      WHERE token = "comment_token" 
     ) 
ELSE (INSERT INTO upvotes(user_token,comment_token 
      VALUES('user_token','comment_token'
     ) 
     AND 
     (UPDATE comments 
      SET upvote = upvote -1 
      WHERE token = "comment_token"
     ) 
END IF
```

but this error occur

`Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0) SQL query: Copy Documentation`

Comment: Anonymous blocks does not supported. PS. This is NOT MySQL error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a normal sql query. You must do this in a [function or stored pricedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `testdb1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT user_token FROM upvotes WHERE user_token ="user_token" AND comment_token = "comment_token")) THEN 
    DELETE FROM upvotes WHERE user_token = 'user_token' AND comment_token = "comment_token";
    UPDATE comments SET upvote = upvote +1 WHERE token = "comment_token" ;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO upvotes(user_token,comment_token) VALUES('user_token','comment_token');
    UPDATE comments SET upvote = upvote -1 WHERE token = "comment_token";
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And you  would collit:

```
call new_procedure();
```